# Scale entire R plot

Tags: r, svg

To work around the problem that the [Word PDF export imposes a minimum line width on embedded SVG graphics](https://superuser.com/q/1709965/176568), I need to create scaled versions of my R plots. For example, instead of

```
svg(file="plotA.svg", width=5.9, height=3)
```

I'd want to create an SVG with 10 times the size:

```
svg(file="plotAx10.svg", width=59, height=30)
```

At the same time, I don't want anything in the plot to change relative to each other. So `plotAx10.svg` scaled to 10% should be exactly the same as `plotA.svg`.

I can achieve most of what I want with the `cex` and `lwd` graphics parameters, e.g. with `par(cex=0.8*10, lwd=10)`. However there are some functions, which don't seem to take them into account. Is this the right approach? Or did I miss some other global scale parameter? If not, which functions need to be configured separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no global scaling parameter. `cex` and `lwd` are a good start, but you'll also need to modify a few other function calls. If you do so, however, you'll get a (sub-)pixel perfect scaled up version of your plots.

For scaling plots in SVG export, I'd define the scale factor in a variable, e.g.

```
sc = 10
```

You'll then need to use it in `svg` and `par`:

```
svg(file="...", width=sc*5.9, height=sc*3)
par(cex=sc*0.8, lwd=sc)
```

Whenever you set `lwd` or `cex` on a graphics function explicitly, that value needs to be multiplied by `sc`. Also, the following commands don't take the settings from `par`, so you'll need to explicitly set the scaled values to them, e.g. with

```
axis(..., lwd=par()[["lwd"]])
mtext(..., cex=par()[["cex"]])
```

The `points` function is an exception to this rule. If you have set the `cex` parameter to that function, e.g.

```
points(..., cex=0.72)
```

this call needs to stay as it is. The `points` function seems to internally multiply the parameter value with the value global `cex`.